# How did I just build the Shootbanger in Dead Space 3 for zero cost?

Tags: dead-space-3

I'm on my second play through of Dead Space 3 in normal difficulty, having used the New Game+ option.  I was just at a workbench, and saw that the Shootbanger weapon was listed for zero tungsten, semiconductor and scrap metal cost.  So I built it, and then its cost changed to 620/2450/3750 for those parts.  What's that about?  Did I earn some kind of perk that gave me a discount?  I had recently spent some ration seals to purchase the Epic Resource pack, but I don't remember that saying anything about weapon discounts.

If it matters, I'm in Chapter 7, at the Roanoke getting the parts for the flight recorder.  I noticed that after getting the parts and going to the workbench to construct it, the Shootbanger cost is now down to 300/850/1350.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The materials showing are what you need to buy to construct the item (e.g. in your first example you need 620 more (tungsten?).

If you have enough materials already the cost will be zero and the blueprint is just a shortcut for building it manually.